# 'Bad Gateway' nginx with docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm new to docking on NGINX and I think I may have made some mistakes, but come on. I built my application and dockerized it normally and in the end on my own VPS I ran the 'docker-compe up' and got success, accessing my server's IP on the port I mapped on nginx it works, however the problem is when I'm configuring in a DNS, follow my code to explain better:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - animes-lobby
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 
      POSTGRES_DB: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    command: >
      bash -c "yarn build
      && yarn typeorm migration:run
      && yarn start:prod"
    networks:
      - animes-lobby
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
      - ./backend/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - db
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    command: >
      bash -c "yarn build
      && yarn start"
    networks:
      - animes-lobby
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/frontend
    depends_on:
      - backend
networks:
  animes-lobby:
    driver: bridge
```

moment that I run the docker-compose up

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                              NAMES
9bb32ec92e61   animeslobbycom_frontend   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   30 seconds ago   Up 28 seconds   0.0.0.0:3000-3001->3000-3001/tcp   animeslobbycom_frontend_1
8b0f09b039e4   animeslobbycom_backend    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   36 seconds ago   Up 29 seconds   0.0.0.0:4000-4001->4000-4001/tcp   animeslobbycom_backend_1
ed14f72e9db8   postgres                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   36 seconds ago   Up 36 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp             animeslobbycom_db_1
```

as mentioned, now I can access it via IP: PORT and it works perfectly, but when I do my virtualhost configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name animeslobby.com www.animeslobby.com;

        location / {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
}
```

I have as a Bad Gateway return in the domain response, someone who has been through this, can you help me?

Comment: You'll need to check your nginx error log but I assume it might be because you haven't specified the document root (of where your files are) via `root /PATH/TO/FILES;`

Comment: Super unclear - what is the `nginx` service in your `docker-compose.yml`? Is running outside of `docker`? If it's your `frontend` service then your `command` would override the `nginx` containers `CMD` so you're not actually running `nginx`...

Comment: error says "connect() failed (111 connection refused) while connecting to upstream", about root, it isn't required while im using proxy_pass

Comment: Where is the nginx server running, on the host?

Comment: @masseyb yeah on the host only, as mentioned, i can access app by ip:port on browser

Comment: Being able to access the service using the IP:PORT is expected when you map the ports from the container to the host... Would start with removing the nginx service from the host and adding it to the `docker-compose.yml` as a new service, then you could `proxy_pass` to using the service name and stop mapping the ports to the host.

Comment: And how are you testing? `curl` from the host or ... because if animeslobby.com is your actual hostname then you're obviously behind cloudflare which implies possible extra config.

Comment: @masseyb yes i am using cloudflare, but there is no way to run nginx on the host directing to the container ports? Because it would be pointless for me to get access to the IP from the VPS, and not be able to do the proxy

Comment: Can get it to work yes but gross imho, `nginx` in `docker` and no ports mapped to the host other than `nginx` ftw. Does a `netstat -an |grep 3000` return i.e. `... :::3000 ... LISTEN`? Can append the URI to the `proxy_pass`, restart the `nginx` service then test (e.g. update `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:3000/` - trailing slash)?

Comment: I already tried to add the bar at the end of the address and even then it doesn't work, I managed to get this through the nginx logs on the vps, netstat connects normally on port 3000

Comment: what really got me confused is to get access by ip and port and not when I am handling a DNS

Comment: It really shouldn't, connecting by IP:PORT when you're mapping the ports from the container to the host is pretty normal, is a direct connection to the service on the port (bypassing any `nginx` server). Can keep the trailing slash  in the `proxy_pass`and replace the `server_name` with a catch all for testing (e.g. `server_name _;`)?

Comment: I tried to direct the dns to a static file and it worked, it seems that the problem is only when I do the proxy_pass, I put the _ and even then it returns 502, it seems that the problem itself is not the dns but rather when I pass proxy_pass.

Comment: to be specific follows the error that returns in the .log; "2021/03/10 23:38:08 [error] 17462#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.68.26.73, server: animeslobby.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/", host: "www.animeslobby.com""